# Codeigniter base controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, architecture

Is it a good design to have all controllers redirect to the site's base controller with a page identifier as the parameter, then having the base controller redirect based on some logic around that parameter?

```
//base controller

function __construct($fromPage, $toPage) {

    parent::__construct();

    if($toPage == 'member_only') {
       $this->is_logged_in();
    }

}

function is_logged_in($controller) {

   //redirect to appropriate controller from here?

}
```

Some suggestions on base controller practice would be splendid :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is better to build your controllers around your models.

If you have a User model, match it with a User controller. And route all requests related to the User model to the corresponding controller (User). Same with, for example, Article model <-> Article Controller, etc.

Edit: For checking if the user is logged in (or some other common functionality), consider [MY_Controller](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/MY_Controller_-_how_to_extend_the_CI_Controller/i)

Comment: I do have my controllers around my models, I'm just wondering if I should use the base controller like so to handle particular states such as being logged in to load all my controller accordingly.

Comment: To expand on Zack's comment about My_Controller, read Phil Sturgeon's post: [link](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/02/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY)